# How to intercept all http responses in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, httpinterceptor

Is there any possible way to intercept all the network responses ? For example with electron js, I can do something like,

```
protocol.interceptBufferProtocol("http", (request, result) => {
  if (request.url === "http://www.example.com/encryptedkey")
     const decypted = decrypt(result)
     return result(decrypted)
});
```

Once I add the above code, no matter who ( webview / a 3rd party library , or any thing in the electron app ) sends the requests to the `http://www.example.com/encryptedkey` the response receive to the client code is **not** the same response sent from the server. It is **manipulated** by above electron code. **Is there any possible way** to achieve this with a flutter app ? I searched on Google and found this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor/example)
But this won't work as I don't have control with some of the http request as they  sends by 3rd party widget I use in the app.

Therefore I'm looking for a way to create some kind of proxy in between the server and flutter app.

Is this possible with flutter ? Any help regarding this really appreciate.